# Open file location directly with file explorer

Tags: android, android-intent, directory

Is there a possibily that i can open the file location 'directly' with a file explorer?
User can longclick on item and then chooses 'open directory', it should navigate directly to the file (with a file explorer of his/her choice).

Below code works but i need to navigate manually.

Thank you in advance.

```
}
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(item.getDirectory());
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivity(intent);
{
```

Edit:

```
Uri myUri = Uri.parse(item.getDirectory().getPath());
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the Uri for the folder into the Intent.

Change

```
Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(item.getDirectory());
intent.setType("file/*");
```

to

```
Uri myUri = Uri.fromFile(item.getDirectory());
intent.setDataAndType(myUri, "file/*");
```

and it should work.

Note: you need to catch and handle the android.content.ActivityNotFound exception that will be thrown by StartActivity if the user does not have any file explorer application installed that can handle the intent. Or else use this code:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose File Explorer"));
```

Comment: Almost, it tries to search for the file when i pick ES Explorere but doesn`t find it.
When i the other code, pls see edit, it find the file in ES Explorer but i can`t delete it move it etc.
Any ideas? Apologies i`m new to this.

Comment: Please see edit. Unfortunately however I don't think it's possible to have a solution that is guaranteed to work with all 3rd party file explorer apps because it depends on how they process the intent or if they do at all.